# wxHaskell on OS X

Tags: macos, haskell, wxwidgets

I want to use wxHaskell on OS X (Snow Leopard, MacBook Pro).  I was able to install the library successfully and the script below:

```
module Main where
import Graphics.UI.WX

main :: IO ()
main = start hello

hello :: IO ()
hello
  = do f    <- frame    [text := "Hello!"]
       quit <- button f [text := "Quit", on command := close f]
       set f [layout := widget quit]
```

does result in a window being displayed with a single button, as specified.  However, nothing happens when I click the button - I don't even get the visual response of the button turning blue to indicate that it's been depressed (haha, no pun intended).

I've heard that you have to run a package called "macosx-app" on wxHaskell binaries to get them to run, but I can't find this anywhere.  It's not on my machine or (as far as I can tell) in the WX or wxHaskell distros.

Anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: You followed the directions for Mac? http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell/MacOS_X

Comment: Yep, and all is fine except for "/usr/local/wxhaskell/bin/macosx-app -v helloworld"  That command is missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source release](http://code.haskell.org/wxhaskell/) includes a file named `macosx-app-template` in the `bin` directory. This file is used by the following part of the `configure` script to create `macosx-app`:

```
cat > config/macosx-app-temp << EOF
#!/bin/sh
rezcomp="$wxinstallrezcomp"
rezfile="$wxinstallrezfile"

EOF
cat config/macosx-app-temp bin/macosx-app-template > config/macosx-app
rm -f config/macosx-app-temp
chmod a+x config/macosx-app
```

If you already have wxHaskell installed and aren't using the `configure` script, you could presumably just duplicate these steps—i.e., copy `macosx-app-template` to `macosx-app`, make it executable, and add the following lines at the top:

```
#!/bin/sh

libdir=""

wxrezcomp="`wx-config --rezflags`"
wxrezfile=""
if test "$wxrezcomp"; then
  for word in $wxrezcomp; do
    temp="`echo $word | grep '[^_]*_mac-[^r]*r'`"
    if test "$temp"; then
      wxrezfile="$temp"
    fi
  done
fi

if test "$wxrezfile"; then
  wxrezdir="`echo $wxrezfile | sed -e 's|\(.*\)/libwx_mac.*|\1|'`"
  wxinstallrezcomp="`echo \"${wxrezcomp}\" | sed -e \"s|${wxrezdir}|${libdir}|g\"`"
  wxinstallrezfile="`echo \"${wxrezfile}\" | sed -e \"s|${wxrezdir}|${libdir}|g\"`"
fi

rezcomp="$wxinstallrezcomp"
rezfile="$wxinstallrezfile"
```

Note that you need to change `libdir=""` to specify the directory where the wxHaskell library files are installed, and if `wx-config` isn't in your path you'll need to change that line as well.

Comment: Seems that now, wxHaskell (0.12.1.6) is distributed through Cabal; the tar.gz file which Cabal downloads from Hackage lacks a bin/ subdirectory entry, and, needless to say, macosx-app-template. Is there still hope for us Mac nerds?

Answer (score 0):

I installed wxhaskell using cabal, and reading the other explanations I proceed as follows in order to have the macosx-app working:

1. I download the wxhaskell sources from
   http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell/Download
2. I unzip the downloaded file:

   wxhaskell-src-XXX.zip

   where XXX is the version number.
3. I run configure in the unzipped directory. 
   This creates from the template the file config/macosx-app

   `.configure`
4. I copy using sudo the file to the bin directory /usr/local/bin

   sudo cp config/macosx-app /usr/local/bin
5. I delete the directories with the source files

That works for me!